# Select input with jquery depending on other tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to use jQuery to select the checkbox input which is in the following HTML code (checkbox just above the text "MyLabel"):

```js
var el = $("span:contains('MyLabel')").parent().find('input');
console.log(el);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="col-md-1">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.myOption" value="[object Object]">
</td>
<td class="col-md-11">
  <span data-bind="text: label">MyLabel</span>
</td>
```

But it doesn't work.

**EDIT:** I actually don't want to check the checkbox, I just wanna get its proper jquery selector.

Comment: Your `span`'s parent (which is `td` with `col-md-11`), has no `input` as its children. Perhaps you could do it like `$("span:contains('MyLabel')").parent().siblings("td.col-md-1").find("input")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) sibling of parent then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target [`:checkbox` selector](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)

```
 var checkbox = $("span:contains('MyLabel')").parent().prev().find(':checkbox');
```

Here is an example to check it;

```js
var checkbox = $("span:contains('MyLabel')").parent().prev().find(':checkbox');
checkbox.prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td class="col-md-1">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.myOption" value="[object Object]">
  </td>
  <td class="col-md-11">
    <span data-bind="text: label">MyLabel</span>
  </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.prev()`:

```js
var el = $("span:contains('MyLabel')").parent().prev().find('input');
console.log(el);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="col-md-1">
 <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.myOption" value="[object Object]">
</td>
<td class="col-md-11">
 <span data-bind="text: label">MyLabel</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should update javascript code.
Change from **parent()** to **parents()**

```
$("span:contains('MyLabel')").parents().find('input')
```

Answer (score 0):

As your `td`s elements are certainly in a `tr` in a `table`, I added those.

Then, you can use [`closest('tr')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to easily target the parent row, and [`find(':checkbox')`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to select your `checkbox` :

```js
var el = $("span:contains('MyLabel')").closest('tr').find(':checkbox');
el.prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-md-1">
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.myOption" value="[object Object]">
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-11">
      <span data-bind="text: label">MyLabel</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it helps.